# How to get Member.Age from Member.Birthday?

Tags: c#, list, datetime, properties, console

I have a class as below:

```
    class Member
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
        private int _age;
        public int Age
        {
            get { return _age; }
            private set { _age = DateTime.Now.Year - Birthday.Year; }
        }
    }
```

In the Main method, I assign member values and I want to get each member's age, but every result is zero, Why? How to solve this problem? Thanks!

````
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Member> memberList = new List<Member>(); //using System.Collections.Generic;
            memberList.Add(new Member() { Name = "Andy", Birthday = new DateTime(1971, 7, 26)});
            memberList.Add(new Member() { Name = "Mike", Birthday = new DateTime(1982, 1, 17)});
            memberList.Add(new Member() { Name = "Lucy", Birthday = new DateTime(1993, 9, 28)});
            foreach (var m in memberList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.Age); //m.Age = 0 
            }
        }
    }```
````

Comment: You don't need the field `_age` and the private setter. Put you calculation in the getter.

Comment: And BTW: your calculation is wrong; you need to get the number of full years from the TimeSpan `DateTime.Now - Birthday`.

Comment: The problem with your code is that you never call `Setter` method of Age, so in `Getter` method, you receive nothing! I think you don't need to `Setter` and you can get value with calculation in `Getter` method.

Comment: Thanks! You are a great help! @Klaus Gütter

Comment: This is the point. Thanks for your help! @negin motalebi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your class like this because the setter are not doing the operation since youre returning the variable on the get and thats why you got a 0 :

```
  public class Member
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
        public int Age
        {
            get { return DateTime.Now.Year - Birthday.Year;  }
            
        }
    }
```

after that change you can get the agre,btw you can calculate the age easier with a timespan to be more exact.

Comment: Empty setters are missleading. Don't make your coworkers get crazy thinking they can set something they cannot to later find out the setter did nothing.

Comment: Also, isn't `return _age = ...` a typo?

Comment: Simply `public int Age { get { return DateTime.Now.Year - Birthday.Year; } }` is OK! @Cleptus

Comment: @makelot yeah, I was pointing Daniel that the code was wrong

Comment: @makelot Also note that a year difference is not accurate to check the age. If your bday is in agoust, in January it would raise an incorrect value. Check the linked question to better answers

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, age is not just a simple minus calculation. @Cleptus

Answer (score 1):

Please return the age from getter method like this.

```
class Member
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    private int _age;
    public int Age
    {
        get { return DateTime.Now.Year - Birthday.Year; }
        private set { _age = DateTime.Now.Year - Birthday.Year; }
    }
}
```

You can remove the calculation from setter method.

Please see the output-
[image]

Comment: What is the usage of the private setter and the `_age` property?

Comment: Thank you! I know where the problem is! @Karthik96